# Connecting to Azure SQL Database using Microsoft Entra access token

Tags: sql-server, delphi, oauth, azure-sql-database, microsoft-entra-id

In a Delphi application I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL Database using a Microsoft Entra access token as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/permissions-consent-overview). Unfortunately I cannot manage to retrieve a token with the needed scope "https://database.windows.net". During OAuth2 authorization I get the following error:

> AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: a5564c45-c00e-45ba-8e72-d1e05bdefa34(AppName). Resource value from request: https://database.windows.net. Resource app ID: 022907d3-0f1b-48f7-badc-1ba6abab6d66. List of valid resources from app registration: a5564c45-c00e-45ba-8e72-d1e05bdefa34, 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000, 00000012-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. Trace ID: 3e7fbafe-2029-4083-ba57-627d4568c400 Correlation ID: 43961bca-c901-43bf-9b23-c9f2758813f3 Timestamp: 2024-02-07 14:45:05Z

It seems like I need to add according permission in Microsoft Entra App registration, but I could not find how to do it, because there is no such permission in API Permissions -> Add permission.

So essentially the question is how to retrieve an access token with proper scope?

Comment: This tutorial includes a script which configures the scopes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-app-access-sql-database-as-user-dotnet

Comment: Section 4. Configure App Service to return a usable access token

Comment: Thanks, this tutorial helped me find the permission under API Permissions -> APIs my organization uses -> Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 1):

User [mjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80901/mjn) provided a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-app-access-sql-database-as-user-dotnet) which helped me find the needed permission under API Permissions -> Add Permission -> APIs my organization uses -> Azure SQL Database -> user_impersonation